# My Carousel is not working when i loop using vueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have this simple slider like below :

```
<div class="slider__container slider--one bg__cat--3 >
        <div v class="slide__container slider__activation__wrap owl-carousel">

            <!-- Start Single Slide -->
            <div  class="single__slide animation__style01 slider__fixed--height">
                <div class="container">
                    <div  class="row align-items__center" >
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <! -- End Single Slide -->

         </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to loop the single slide using :

```
<template v-for="slide in slides"></template>
```

And at this moment, the slide shows up all slides in one page. The carousel stop working. When i duplicate the code, the slide works fine..

Note please, i use Owl Carousel. Thank you if you can help.

Comment: are you using `vue-owl-carousel` or the base `owl-carousel`

Comment: Thx you for ur interest.  I'm using the the base owl-carousel